# Assign a value on instant search from database

Tags: php, search, instantsearch

Search Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>PHP Live MySQL Database Search</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        font-family: Arail, sans-serif;
    }
    /* Formatting search box */
    .search-box{
        width: 300px;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .search-box input[type="text"]{
        height: 32px;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .result{
        position: absolute;        
        z-index: 999;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }
    .search-box input[type="text"], .result{
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    /* Formatting result items */
    .result p{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 7px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        border-top: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .result p:hover{
        background: #f2f2f2;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
        /* Get input value on change */
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
        if(inputVal.length){
            $.get("backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
                // Display the returned data in browser
                resultDropdown.html(data);
            });
        } else{
            resultDropdown.empty();
        }
    });

    // Set search input value on click of result item
    $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
        $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
        $(this).parent(".result").empty();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="search-box">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="id" name="id" placeholder="Search Products or codes..." />
        <div class="result"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Backend search page:

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", " ", "root");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(isset($_POST['term'])){
    // Prepare a select statement
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ProductCodes WHERE item_name LIKE ?";
    //$sql = "SELECT * FROM ProductCodes WHERE ('item_name' LIKE ?) OR ('id' LIKE ?)";


    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_term);

        // Set parameters
        $param_term = $_REQUEST['term'] . '%';

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

            // Check number of rows in the result set
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                // Fetch result rows as an associative array
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                    echo "<p>BA" . $row["id"] . " " . $row["item_name"] . "</p>";
                }
            } else{
                echo "<p>No matches found</p>";
            }
        } else{
            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
        }
    }
     //var_dump(mysqli_error($db_conx));
    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Please go easy - newbie alert! 
I have set up the above with a table (ProductCodes) which contains two colums - item_name and id.
I need to get the search to check both of the columns but I've tried replacing

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ProductCodes WHERE item_name LIKE ?";
```

with

```
"$sql = "SELECT * FROM ProductCodes WHERE ('item_name' LIKE ?) OR ('id' LIKE ?)";
```

The other problem I have is that I need the value for the form to be the id field only but I can't see how to assign it.
Any help is appreciated, I've tried all sorts of combinations but I'm just going round in circles.

Comment: Quite confused as to what you're trying to achieve here, also check the syntax at the end of your `$sql` you had an extra `"` in this section `LIKE ?";"`. Edited the question to fix this

Comment: You can use `SELECT id FROM ProductCodes WHERE item_name LIKE ? OR id = ?` LIKE is a condition mainly used for strings... But Kate, could you be more specific on what you want? The subject of this it's not really clear. Assing a value to what from what? (You can assume that database searching instantly is redundant for this case)

Comment: You need the same number of `variables` as the number of `?` placeholders. In your case, `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_term, $param_term);`.

Comment: @Rafael -  I get the following error - Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /home/bakeart/specsite.bakeart.co.uk/specsite/ingredients/backend-search.php on line 20
ERROR: Could not able to execute SELECT id FROM ProductCodes WHERE item_name LIKE ? OR id = ?.

Comment: @Isaac When a search is carried out the value of the field is the same as the contents of the field. I need it just to be the id part of the content. eg if the id is 12345 and the item_name is "foobar" I just want the value passed to the next page in a form to be 12345.
I hope this is making sense - I'm trying to learn as quickly as I can...

Answer (score 0):

You can bind parameters like this:

```
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);
```

taken from here: http://php.net/manual/ro/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

In your case this would be:

```
$stmt->bind_param('si', $yourStringValue, $yourIntValue);
```

and you will need to fix your query to not use a `like` for the `id`, which is presumably numeric:

```
"SELECT * FROM ProductCodes WHERE item_name LIKE ? or id = ?"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok Kate, I think I understand your problem. You want to use one single input to search two fields on this query.

Let's start with adapting the query then:

```
$sql = 'SELECT id, item_name FROM ProductCodes WHERE item_name LIKE ? OR id = ?';
```

Then we bind the parameters to it, since there are two **interrogation marks (?)** we will need two parameters.

```
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $searchName, $searchId);

$searchName = '%' . $_REQUEST['term'] . '%';
$searchId = $_REQUEST['term'];
```

Or using the same function you are.

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $searchName, $searchId);

$searchName = '%' . $_REQUEST['term'] . '%';
$searchId = $_REQUEST['term'];
```

Sorry for the mess! Fixed considering the references.

Comment: I get a new error!
Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in /home/bakeart/specsite.bakeart.co.uk/specsite/ingredients/backend-search.php on line 20

Comment: added above! pressed the return button too early

Comment: A-ha... the prepared statement thing, sorry. Moment.

Comment: Ok, **YOU** were correct from the beginning, you only needed to add another variable for the binding.

Comment: Makes a change!  It's sort of working now but only showing the id and not the item_name field. Any ideas?
echo "<p>BA" . $row["id"] . " " . $row["item_name"] . "</p>";

Comment: Yes, I changed that because I understood you only wanted the id for the form. :) returning it.

Comment: ignore that, was just being thick! All sorted now, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Keep rocking. Also, please check this website: https://www.phptherightway.com/ might be quite... enlightening for you. It certainly was for me.

Comment: Thank you for the tip - we've all got to start somewhere!

Comment: Also, is considered good practice in this community to upvote the answers you got and to choose the one that solved your problem. (I also consider a good practice to upvote the questions you answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use two params in query as follow:

```
// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ProductCodes WHERE id = ? OR item_name LIKE ? ");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $ProductCodes,$ID);
$ProductCodes = '%' . $_REQUEST['term'] . '%';
$ID = '%' . $_REQUEST['id'] . '%';
```